# Uso de "cal" como abreviatura de "calle"

Tags: uso-de-palabras, significado, historia, abreviaturas

Trasteando con el *Diccionario de Autoridades*, encuentro de vez en cuando cosas curiosas, como una acepción hoy desaparecida de la palabra *cal*:

> CAL. s. f. Lo mismo que Calle abreviada la pronunciación. Usase en algunas partes de Andalucia, especialmente en Sevilla, donde dicen Cal de Génova, Cal de Francos, &c.

Esta acepción ya estaba marcada como "antigua" en la edición de 1780. Sin embargo, la acepción de "cal" como "calle" se mantuvo en el diccionario hasta la edición de 1992. En la de 2001 desapareció.

Como habitante de Sevilla durante la mayor parte de mi vida, no he encontrado vestigio alguno de que alguna vez se dijera "cal" por "calle" aquí. Así que pregunto: ¿durante qué época fue común usar "cal" como abreviatura de "calle"? ¿Se usó solo en Andalucía o también en otras partes de España? ¿Queda algún vestigio actualmente, como algún cartel antiguo que ponga "Cal de XXX"?

Bonus: ¿por qué la RAE borró esta palabra del diccionario en vez de marcarla como en desuso?

Comment: El uso de Cal se usaba para mencionar una familia. e.g. La familia de Ramón García => Cal García

Comment: A lo mejor esto puede ayudar. La palabra CALL viene del hebreo Qahal (Comunidad), puede ser por influencia del latín (callis: paso estrecho entre dos paredes).  Es la palabra utilizada en Cataluña  para denominar los diversos barrios judíos

Comment: Quizás la famosa expresión "En ca l'abuela" venga de ese uso de familia y realmente sea "en Cal de la abuela" y se ha mezclado con la evolución de las hablas andaluzas perdiendo la ele final

Comment: Al menos en mi pueblo en Córdoba solo se decía  "calle" con todas sus letras.  Era frecuente emplear la palabra cal, pero la cal de encalar, es decir, del óxido de calcio para pintar las paredes.  Sí creo haber escuchado,  o quizás leído en alguna novela,  "ca' Mengano"  o "ca' Fulano", pero siempre con el significado de casa y en todo caso no creo que se use mucho hoy día.

Comment: Esto se usa hoy día, al menos en Alicante. Entiendo que viene del valenciano/catalán, pues en ese idioma es una expresión que significa "casa de". Ejemplos: "vaig ca la iaia (voy ca la abuela)", ca+el=cal: "va cal Pep (va cal Pepe, a casa del Pepe)". Ya no sé si el caso de uso en Andalucía está relacionado con esto o no.